# Convert CSV file into 2D Table in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, parsing, data-structures

I have a CSV file with the following structure:

```
Configuration ID, Value (1), Value (2), ......., Value (N)
Config (1)      , X (1)    , X (2)    , ......., X (N)
Config (2)      , Y (1)    , Y (2)    , ......., Y (N)
```

The configuration ID for each row is unique across the file.

I want to read this CSV file in Python (v3.8) and be able to lookup for a particular value by passing both the Config ID and Value ID (Something like 2D dictionary)

```
print(dataStucture[Config (1)][Value (2)])
```

The previous syntax should print: X(2)

Is there any embedded function in Python that parses a CSV file and converts it into 2D dictionary or any data structure that allows me to pass two unique keys to fetch a value from the CSV file? Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use pandas to read the CSV into a dataframe. Syntax: `df=pandas.read.csv("path_to_file.csv")`

Comment: @IoT, does my answer solve your question?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf it solves my question. But what Jacob stated using pandas and data frame is more suitable as it provides more flexibility to manipulate my data. However, in addition to the above answer, Jacob should state which column is used for indexing too.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use `pandas` but `csv` instead, you can use the following code:

```py
import csv

data_stucture = {}
with open('sample.csv') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    header = next(spamreader, None)  # skip the headers
    for row in spamreader:
        data_stucture[row[0].strip()] = {
            key.strip(): value.strip() for key, value in zip(header[1:], row[1:])
        }
```

Considering how the file is structured, the content of `data_structure` will be

```
{'Config (1)': {'Value (1)': 'X (1)', 'Value (2)Value (N)': 'X (2)'},
 'Config (2)': {'Value (1)': 'Y (1)', 'Value (2)Value (N)': 'Y (2)'}}
```

This means you will be able to get `"X (1)"` by using `data_stucture['Config (1)']['Value (1)']`.